# Can I use another computer as a second monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

Is there a way to extend my desktop's screen onto my laptop's display, as if the laptop was just another monitor in a dual-monitor configuration?

Maybe with some combination of VNC and Synergy?

Comment: xdmx is really stale, but it was built to do exactly this

Comment: Same question on Super User: [using a second computer as a mere screen/monitor in X (VNC?)](http://superuser.com/q/115073/)

Answer (score -1):

I believe with the Nvidia-xserver-settings you can accomplish that provided you have an Nvidia card. You select twinview mode and designate the external monitor as primary and the laptop screen as secondary. That should do the trick.

If you have other graphic cards I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: I don't think that's what he was asking. You can't generally output *to* a laptop display from an external source, unless maybe some of the HDMI/DisplayPort having cards/laptops somehow allow it.

Comment: Ahh I see it now, my apologies, got it wrong the first time